# Does site-id/itemId on Sharepoint get regenerated without being prompted?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-files

Context:
I find DriveItem's with request calls like the following:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/knockycode.sharepoint.com,{siteId},{driveId}/drive/items/{itemId}/children
```

Keep in mind that `{siteId}`, `{driveId}`, and `{itemId}` are placeholders. Examples values are `01CGQD2IXV5WLDIQPZH5CLXFCTZCV2ERYC`, not guids like `44434afe-d8fb-470e-904e-fc865e029b30`

Question:
I persist in my database these Id values with the assumption that they will not be regenerated on the SharePoint side. Unless I go on SharePoint and do the "Reset all Document IDs" action.

Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Is your itemid a documentLibrary?

Comment: No, my itemid is a document within the documentLibrary. I always get the siteId and driveId with the Filter query so I'm not worried about those ids changing and thus making my request calls return no results.